# How to remove pattern lock without data loss?

Tags: security, 5.1-lollipop, locked-out, pattern-lock, password-protection

I have **intex aqua super** mobile with android 5.1 os.
I aslo try google recovery find my device method but that not working.
How to recover pattern lock without data loss?
Device is not rooted.
Developer mode is disabled.

Comment: Have you already checked with our [locked-out tag-wiki](/tags/locked-out/info)? If not, please do so. The first question linked there has a full list of approaches. If nothing of that helped, we will need more details – eg. is the device rooted, is USB debugging enabled, what have you already tried and where did you get stuck.

Comment: @Izzy i already check this. But I unable to resolve that issue. Because in my phone only pattern lock is enabled and other password i.e. Pin password is disabled. Also Google's email recovery find my phone also not working. I also try to recover my password by locking it by find my phone google recovery but there is no option for forgot password menu.

Comment: The entire question I've mentioned is about "plain pattern lock", and there are several additional approaches mentioned – but AFAIR they require at least one of root or USB debugging (or both) being available. I assume you haven't unlocked your bootloader? If you have, there would be a chance via booting a custom recovery from an image (or flashing it).

Comment: @Izzy hu how to create image of my phone is there DD command is useful n or not? Also when I connect mobile to computer USB data share also disabled. And USB only function as charger. I think After creating image flashing is harmless...? How to create image of android phone in my laptop Ubuntu 16.04 os installed.

Comment: Yes, `dd` would be the tool of your choice for creeating images of your device's partitions. Trouble is, how will you run it? I could recommend you a tool creating the appropriate scripts which you then just would need to run – but with USB debugging disabled, that wouldn't work. I assume you've neither unlocked your bootloader, so booting a custom recovery isn't an option either.